# How do I align an image to the right of a block of text using Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I want to do is move the placeholder image to the space to the right of the text.

I've tried several solutions involving adding different classes to the image, removing the nested container, and so on, but nothing moves the image up next to the text.  The image resizes depending on the col-x of the left column but it refuses to move up.  From what I can tell in the Bootstrap documentation and my experience working with Flexbox this seems like it ought to work but I guess I'm missing something?  Can anyone help?

Here's an image of my page as it is:

[image: screencap of my project]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container'>
  <hr />
  <!-- begin template -->
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-8'>
      <div class='container-fluid p-0'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col'>
            <h3>Project Name</h3>
          </div>
          <div class='col text-end'>
            <p>Project Status</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col'>
            <p><i class='fa fa-arrow-right'></i> Tech 1, Tech 2, Tech 3</p>
          </div>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='col'>
              <p>This is a description of the project, its goals, its challenges, the technologies it uses.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-4'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100' class='img-fluid' alt='placeholder image'>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre] so we can follow along ?

Comment: Your layout seems needlessly complex. Why is it important to have every line of text in its own row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as I see it, is that you've made a mistake with your overall structure. The first 8 unit column and the 4 unit column which contains the image should be in the same row. I've added one of the missing closing div tags ahead of the latter to achieve that.

I'm not sure this is what you want since your specifications are a bit ambiguous. My advice, though, is to start any layout from the outside, establishing your primary structure first, then add interior structure. It's easy to see what went wrong if you work a step at a time.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container'>
  <hr />
  <!-- begin template -->
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-8'>
      <div class='container-fluid p-0'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col'>
            <h3>Project Name</h3>
          </div>

          <div class='col text-end'>
            <p>Project Status</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col'>
            <p><i class='fa fa-arrow-right'></i> Tech 1, Tech 2, Tech 3</p>
          </div>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='col'>
              <p>This is a description of the project, its goals, its challenges, the technologies it uses.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-4'>
      <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100' class='img-fluid' alt='placeholder image'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking this over but I'm pretty sure the col-8 and col-4 *are* nested within the same div-row tag?  Even looking at my original sample they both appear to be at the second indent, and as far as I can see all the opening tags correspond to the correct closing tags.

Comment: Oop, upon re-examining my code I found an unmatched div tag for one of the rows of the inner container.  Knew I was missing something.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container'>
  <hr />
  <!-- begin template -->
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-8'>
      <div class='container-fluid p-0'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col'>
            <h3>Project Name</h3>
          </div>
          <div class='col text-end'>
            <p>Project Status</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col'>
            <p><i class='fa fa-arrow-right'></i> Tech 1, Tech 2, Tech 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-8'>
            <p>This is a description of the project, its goals, its challenges, the technologies it uses.</p>
          </div>
          <div class='col-4'>
            <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100' class='img-fluid' alt='placeholder image'>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Answers should contain some explanation. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container'>
  <hr />
  <!-- begin template -->
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-8'>
      <div class='container-fluid p-0'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col'>
            <h3>Project Name</h3>
          </div>
          <div class='col text-end'>
            <p>Project Status</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col'>
            <p><i class='fa fa-arrow-right'></i> Tech 1, Tech 2, Tech 3</p>
          </div>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='col'>
              <p>This is a description of the project, its goals, its challenges, the technologies it uses.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>          
    </div>
    <div class='col-4'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100' class='img-fluid' alt='placeholder image'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).